# Powershell. Increase value in CSV file or Array

Tags: arrays, powershell, csv

I have a CSV file that looks like:

```
Initials,Size excl. Backup/Pst,Number of warnings
USER1,100,1
USER2,100,1
USER4,400,2
```

I would like to increase the value "Number of warnings" by 1 so I will end up with:

```
Initials,Size excl. Backup/Pst,Number of warnings
USER1,100,2
USER2,100,2
USER4,400,3
```

I have tried, but not succeeded.
I have also tried putting it in array, but can't get it working.

```
$Temp = Import-Csv $Database | foreach {$_.'Number of warnings' +1}
```

But this does 2 things:
only adds 1 to the end of the number so 1 becomes 11 and 2 becomes 21 (as it was a string)
The output is only the "Number of warnings" column - the rest of my information seems to be gone

Comment: I think you just forgot to assign the addition...
{$_'Number of warnings' = $_'Number of warnings' +1}

Comment: Sorry Schwarzie2478, it fails. When I add the dot  {$_.'Number of warnings' = $_.'Number of warnings' +1} it does not fail anymore, but $Temp is empty

Comment: You might be able to use `foreach {$_.'Number of warnings'++}` too

Comment: @AthomSfere I tried that, but it doesn't cast the `string` to an `int` and throws an error about the `++` operator only working on numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works :

```
$myreport = Import-Csv .\testing.csv

$myreport | %{$_.'Number of warnings' = 1 + $_.'Number of warnings'}
```

Comment: So putting the "1" in front, made PS change it from an string to an INT. clever...

Comment: @Lisbjerg you could also explicitly cast it to an `int` with `[int]$_.'Number of warnings'+1`

Comment: Just to make it clear, pay attention with the casting, make sure you don't cast the resulting string to integer.  You'll have to add a lot of parenthesis to make sure, the casting happens before the addition...  aah the joys of dynamic programming :-)